# custom QStyledItemDelegate class: editors are not on right place

Tags: c++, qt

I am tring to customise QStyledITemDelegate that use QComboBox on some columns  displayed by QTableView with an model. 
I have reimplemented the **updateGeometry**  below:

```
void MyDelegate::updateEditorGeometry(QWidget* editor,QStyleOptionViewItem& option,
                                      const QModelIndex& index)const
 {   if(index.isValid())        
     editor->setGeometry(option.rect);
 }
```

but it didn't work,the combobox just on the top left corner

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pwHJH.png)

here is the  Aplllication Output:

> setGeometry: Unable to set geometry 49x36+50+37 on QWidgetWindow/'QComboBoxClassWindow'. Resulting geometry:  152x36+50+37 (frame: 9, 38, 9, 9, custom margin: 0, 0, 0, 0, minimum size: 0x0, maximum size: 16777215x16777215).

So I am confused why it didn't work;the whole source code of my delegate class below. Any help greatly appreciated, thanks for reading!

```
#include<QObject>
#include <QStyledItemDelegate>
class QSqlTableModel;
class MyDelegate : public QStyledItemDelegate
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    MyDelegate(QObject* parent,QSqlTableModel* model);
    QWidget* createEditor(QWidget* parent,
                          const QStyleOptionViewItem& option,const QModelIndex& index)const override;
    void updateEditorGeometry(QWidget* editor,
                              QStyleOptionViewItem& option,const QModelIndex& index)const override;
   // void setEditorData(QWidget* deitor,const QModelIndex & index)const;
  // void setModelData(QWidget* editor,QAbstractItemModel& index)const;
private:
   QSqlTableModel* _model;
};

MyDelegate::MyDelegate(QObject* parent,QSqlTableModel* model)
   :QStyledItemDelegate(parent)
{ 
  _model=model;
}
  QWidget* MyDelegate::createEditor(QWidget* parent,
           const QStyleOptionViewItem& option, const QModelIndex& index)const
{
if(index.column()==1||index.column()==2)
 {
    QComboBox* comboBox_1 =new QComboBox();
    comboBox_1->setModel(_model);
    comboBox_1->setModelColumn(index.column());
    return comboBox_1;
 }

   else return QStyledItemDelegate::createEditor(parent,option,index);

}
void MyDelegate::updateEditorGeometry(QWidget* editor,QStyleOptionViewItem& option,const QModelIndex& index) const
  {   if(index.isValid())

    editor->setGeometry(option.rect);

 }
```

Comment: Your `QComboBox` lacks parent, that's most likely the reason of the problem. Try to change the initialization of your editor to `QComboBox* comboBox_1 =new QComboBox(parent);` and see if it would help.

Comment: Thanks！it works. but i don't understand why  editors must have a parent widget(i just know it make memory management  easier); why **editor->setGeometry(option.rect)**  can't work enough?

Comment: As [Qt documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#geometry-prop) says: "geometry : QRect. This property holds the geometry of the widget relative to its parent and excluding the window frame". Without a parent for the widget Qt pretty much doesn't know how to actually set the geometry.